# Django, F object should be passed to my own function

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm

I want to fetch leave requests of all employees where from date should be greater than each employees individual current time in their timezone.

So I need to get Timezone and convert it to current employee timezone datetime.

But im getting error that F object value is not passed as a value in to the function but as a F object.

How to pass F object into the function or any solution to get current employee timezone and convert it to timezone current time?

```
LeaveRequest.objects.filter(from_date__gte=my_own_func(F('request__employee___user__timezone'))
```

Comment: What is the code of `my_own_func` ?

Comment: The ORM creates SQL and executes this on the db server. So unless `my_own_func` is a function on the db server this approach can not work. And if it is a db function you'll first have to configure the ORM to use it.

Comment: It is not a db function.It is just a function which takes timezone info inside and returns current date in the given timezone info

Comment: so any other alternative way to filter records based on each record's employee's current date in their time zone